# List all site collections titles and descriptions

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to generate a list of all site collections with their URLs, Titles and Descriptions.
While I was googling it, I noticed that most of the scripts are using `Get-SPWebApplication` and `Get-SPSite` but the "Description" is attached to `Get-SPWeb`.

Is there a way to list them all at once?

Thanks

Artur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
 Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select-Object -Property Title, Url, Description
```

If you need to know urls of root webs only you can use following code:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Where { $_.IsRootWeb } | Select-Object -Property Title, Url, Description
```

Comment: Default scope for Get-SPSite is farm scope, so it should return all site collections within your farm